# Python-Webbrowser module doesn't work on terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal, python-webbrowser

My code is here:

```
import webbrowser
import time

print("Directing to youtube")
webbrowser.open("http://www.youtube.com", new=1)
time.sleep(3)
```

This runs in *pycharm's terminal* perfectly but it doesn't work in *mac's own terminal*.
I installed a third party terminal *iTerm* later but it didn't worked there to.
The problem is with the webbrowser module, It doesn't open up the webpage.

Comment: Do you have any error messages that you could share?

Comment: Use `webbrowser.open("http://www.youtube.com", new=1)` note the `"`

Comment: I forgot to add it in the question. Sorry. It's not working again :(